# Naming conventions for rspec tests with zeitwerk expecting model_spec.rb to define constant ModalSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, autoload, ruby-on-rails-7, zeitwerk

I'm working on upgrading rails, and part of that process involves switching from the classic autoloader to zeitwerk.  I've been running `bin/rails zeitwerk:check` and handling all the cases that come up, and I've now come to a spec file. Up until now it has been the odd case of adding an inflection or renaming the constant:

```
Rails.autoloaders.each do |autoloader|
      autoloader.inflector.inflect(
        'aes' => 'AES',
      )
    end
```

The following is the convention I've always known for rspec tests, and I can't find anything that contradicts that this is still the convention:

```
  # spec/models/user_spec.rb

  require 'rails_helper'

  RSpec.describe User do
    # test stuff
  end
```

However, user_spec.rb does not define UserSpec, and zeitwerk isn't having it.

From what I can tell, I have 3 options:

1. go against the standard rspec convention, and rename all the constants in all the tests such as from User to UserSpec
2. define a 'dummy' module in every test that defines the constant
3. add an inflection in application.rb for every single test.

All of these seem like terrible ideas.  What is everyone else doing here? Is there a 4th option I haven't seen?

Comment: That spec should stay as it is. The spec directory is not expected to be in the autoload paths. Why does the application have it? Note that file was not autoloadable before either, only zeitwerk:check is now telling you.